# Why is my Bundle inside android.os.Message being reset?

Tags: java, android, mobile

In an Activity, I have some snippet of code that fires off a Message:

```
        Message m = _handler.obtainMessage( UPDATE_PROGRESS );
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt( BUNDLE_KEY, 50 );
        m.setData( bundle );
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "value " + bundle.getInt( BUNDLE_KEY, 0 ) ); // prints 50
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "sent:" + _handler.sendMessage( m ) ); // prints true
```

In another part of the Activity, I am handling it like this:

```
    public void handleMessage( final android.os.Message msg ) 
    {
        switch( msg.what )
        {
        case UPDATE_PROGRESS:
            post( new Runnable() 
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Bundle aBundle = msg.getData();
                    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "value in bundle=" + 
                         aBundle.getInt( BUNDLE_KEY, 0 ) ); // prints 0

                    Log.d( LOG_TAG, "contains 'progress' : " + 
                         aBundle.containsKey( BUNDLE_KEY ) ); // prints 'false'

                }
            });
            break;
          }
```

Why is the Bundle not preserved in the Message ? Who is resetting the values of the Bundle ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is solved. Basically in the handleMessage method, don't wrap the lambdas inside a Runnable. Execute your modifications in-situ.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old thread, but since I had a similar problem using a Handler with HandlerThread I wanted to add some info about how I solved it.

I noticed that the contents of my Message instance was being sporadically cleared after invoking quit on the HandlerThread.  To fix it I made a copy of the Message object inside the handleMessage callback with a new reference by using: `Message msgCopy = Message.obtain(msg);`.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else found this question trying to solve the same problem as me:

If you're creating a message like so (i.e., setting a bundle as the message's obj):

```
Bundle myBundle = new Bundle();
myBundle.putString("CODE", "code");

//send bundle to target
handlerOfTarget.obtainMessage(MESSAGE_TRIGGER_RECEIVED, 0, 0, myBundle).sendToTarget();
```

(Where handlerOfTarget is a reference to the target's handler)

And trying to receive the bundle like this:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    case MESSAGE_TRIGGER_RECEIVED:
        Bundle myBundle = msg.getData();
        String code = myBundle.getString("CODE"); //null

        ...
```

The problem is that msg.getData() doesn't get the bundle that is set as the message's object.

To do so, you need to use:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(Message msg) {

    case MESSAGE_TRIGGER_RECEIVED:
        Bundle myBundle = (Bundle) msg.obj;
        String code = myBundle.getString("CODE"); //null

        ...
```